# Custom ListAdapter consisting of EditText lose focus called twice

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, listener

I am making a E-commerce app whose cart list has a custom `ListView` which consist of `EditText`. The `EditText` represents the quantity of item. I am using `OnFocusChangeListener` to detect when a customer is done changing the quantity of the item then updating the cart on server. Everything is working fine, just the `onFocusChange` is being called twice i.e. I am getting `false` twice.

```
viewHolder.etProductQuantity.setOnFocusChangeListener( new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {

        if(!hasFocus){

            // Updating the ProductList class's object to set the new quantity
            // Updating product quantity on server
            Log.d("Product Quantity", viewHolder.etProductQuantity.getText().toString() + b);
        }
    }
});
```

Thus, the coding is being executed twice which is creating problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following line into your activity in the manifest fixed the problem:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Not sure why though.

Comment: This is working fine too but I want to know why it is being called twice.

Answer (score 1):

You may use like this:

```
edt_sys_log_search.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                    //do calling WS                 
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

and set EditText property as follows:

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
singleLine="true"
```

It will call WS when user press Done from SoftKeyboard

Comment: For some reasons, onEditorAction is not being triggered. I am using genymotion right now and it doesn't have a soft keyboard so that might be the issue, I'll check on real device and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Try to maintain one flag which check is lost focus code executed one time then never executed again :

```
viewHolder.etProductQuantity.setTag(1);
viewHolder.etProductQuantity.setOnFocusChangeListener( new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus && ((Integer)view.getTag())==1){
                    // Updating the ProductList class's object to set the new quantity
                    // Updating product quantity on server
                    Log.d("Product Quantity",                    
                    viewHolder.etProductQuantity.getText().toString() + b);
                    view.setTag(0);
                }else{
                    view.setTag(1);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is working fine but can you tell me why editText lost focus is being called twice?