# Android (Lollipop) EditText onFocus fired multiple times

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-5.0-lollipop, onfocus

I have a couple of EditTexts with onFocusChangeListeners

```
// When the field gains or loses focus
txtMinimumValue.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        editFocusChange(view, hasFocus);
    }
});
```

I'm not having any issues on pre-Lollipop devices, but any Nexus 5's and the onFocusChange is fired about 7 times.

I found this SO: [Custom ListAdapter consisting of EditText lose focus called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100534/custom-listadapter-consisting-of-edittext-lose-focus-called-twice)

and then I found this Android Open Source Issue that looks related: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80180
A Project Member said, "The framework version does this too. Fixed for a future release." Anyway to know when appcompat-v7:21.0.3 is released and I can test if this fixes my issue?

Anyone having this same issue?

Comment: I suggest you leaving your solution as an answer and accept it, so that people can see that this question has a solution.

Comment: How did you hear about 21.0.3 ? Is there any website that shows a "what's new" of this? including what was fixed?

Comment: The Open Source issue mentions v21.0.2 (or lower), and that there is a fix coming. I assumed that the fix would be in 21.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

I have numerous filter screens where I might have several views on top and edit boxes, and then a list of values in a `ListView`. I've been dynamically building the bottom list view of values from arrays, and then programmatically building the top section of views and adding this top section as a header view. This is so the entire screen scrolls together, b/c you shouldn't add a `ListView` to a `ScrollView`.

Any `EditText` views on the top section might have `onFocusChange` methods to adjust the filter values manually entered. On Lollipop, there must be a bug where these programmatically built views added as a `ListView` header don't work, b/c the `onFocusChange` methods were firing repeatedly. I had to build the top as an xml for the `onFocusChange` methods to fire correctly.